# Jenkins: find out which project is using a specific plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is there a way to list all Jenkins projects using the SonarQube plugin? We have some projects have SonarQube integrated in the build, I need to modify these projects.

Answer (score 2):

You can just go to jenkins folder and search for config files which uses your plugin:

```
grep -l -r --include config.xml "SonarPublisher" $JENKINS_HOME/jobs
```

folder names in output will match job names.

Comment: My config.xml file doesn't have any project and plugin information inside, only roles and permissions.

Comment: @Jirong Hu : make sure you look at job's `config.xml` at `jobs` folder not to main one